# User need to write the correct answer in edittext to go to the next level

Tags: android

I am making a question game and the user need to write the correct answer in `EditText` to get to the next level.

I am struggeling to find a way to make `EditText` check if the user wrote the right answer and go to the next level at the same time

I need:

- A place to store the answer.
- `EditText` to check the answer (if answer is right, go to next level).
- (If answer is wrong, delete text).
- Auto start next level if answer is correct.
- And finish that level (so the user cant go back).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String userEntry = editText.getText().toString();
if(userEntry.equals(correctAnswer)) {
    goToNextLevel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a button to check the edit text, add an onclicklistener to the button and then inside it get the text of the edit text and use string.equal to find out if it's right. If it's right, advance to the next level.

Typing on my phone, sorry for the poor formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Take look on the steps in this chapter of the book :

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/android/9780133077698/6dot-flag-quiz-game-app/ch06

you can get the source code for free and learn from it how to make stuff work.